# What might be the meaning of the word or phrase 'こよかな'

Tags: words

I cannot really comprehend koyokana in the following short sentence:
shoppu itte koyokana.

What meaning does koyokana give to the "shoppu itte" part.
How could I divide koyokana in mind:
koyo ka na  or ko yo ka na

Comment: Could it be `～来ようかな`?

Comment: mm I think it might be:) though i haven't met with this before like this itte koyou kana.:)
Eventhough I did see kuru as the following ittekimasu. maybe ittekoyou ka na is a more informal way.

Comment: It's certainly 来ようかな, as in 行ってくる + volitional + the reflective かな. Did you originally see it written in romaji?

Comment: no I saw i written in hiragana and kanji this way ショップ行ってこよかな

Comment: @ssb is correct. This is just very casual. Think of when you use "I gotta go" or something like that.

Comment: Thank you so I could translate shoppu ittekoyokana as I gotta go to boutique/shop?:)

Comment: No, I meant "gotta" as an example of shortened speech. This is more like "Should I go?"

"I gotta go" would be 行かなきゃ or 行かないと。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

" ショップ行ってこよかな " is a slangy way of saying the following:

> ショップへ行って来ようかな

Assuming the subject is first person, here is how one can break it down:

ショップへ  To the store

行って来よう Shall I go [to the store] (literally "shall I go to the store and come back").                                     *行ってこよう is the volitional form of 行ってくる. Without a question word, this could be translated as "Let's go [to the store]."

か question word

な indicates pondering this question. As a particle at the end of a sentence, な can denote emotion or emphasis. The more extended it is the more emphasis, i.e.,"なぁぁぁぁ。。。 "

So in natural English, the sentence ショップへ行って来ようかな becomes:

> Hmmm, should I go to the store or not?